# Symmetry of an object suspended inside another object

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

I am from a chemistry background and I haven't taken abstract algebra, so it is possible that this question may be basic. This is the problem that I have:

Suppose that I have an object A, which is a tetrahedron inside a cube. By applying all symmetry operations on A, I can determine the space group of the object.

This seems rather cumbersome. One has to worry about the position of each object as well as the dimension (i.e. whether it is a triangle, square, hypercube, etc).
For example:

[image]

Has a different symmetry than:

[image]

I was wondering whether there were some relations that I could take advantage of to simplify the problem.

Is there a theorem that says something along the lines of:

**If an object has symmetry x and is inside an object of symmetry y,  the highest symmetry attainable is z?**

Comment: I don't think I quite follow. You could align the centroids of a small tetrahedron inside a large cube, and the symmetries for the individuals would be completely different. I can't be sure of all the cases, but I would guess that the system as a whole doesn't have any nontrivial symmetries.

On the other hand, you could swap the cube for a sphere, and then the symmetries for the sphere would contain those of the tetrahedron, so that the symmetries of the whole system were the same as the tetrahedron.

Comment: I mean, it seems clear that the symmetry of the combined system would just be the intersection of the individual symmetry groups.

Comment: @rschwieb Is there a book/article that shows an example of how to take the interesection of two symmetry groups?

Comment: Well... if you had your rigid object in $\mathbb R^n$, you would presumably find the symmetry group in $SO(n)$ for each, and then just take the set intersection...